# load testing socket.io chat with artillery.io and validating a JSON response

Tags: node.js, socket.io, performance-testing, load-testing

Folks, I am using the following code to load test my socket.io based chat application. The response I am sending from the chat is in JSON format. But I am unable to cross verify using artillery.io. I am receiving "data is not valid:1" in Errors. How can I verify JSON response in artillery.io socket.io testing?

```
  target: "http://127.0.0.1:9092"
  environments:
   debug:
    phases:
     -
     duration: 1
     arrivalRate: 1
  scenarios:
  -
  engine: "socketio"
  flow:
   -
    emit:
      channel: "chatevent"
      data: {"userName": "jj", "message": "hello","displayName":"John"}
      response:
        channel: "chatevent"
        data: {"userName": "jk", "message": "world","displayName":"Jack"}
```